# Change Pulumi's timeout when deploying Kubernetes resources

Tags: kubernetes, pulumi

When I deploy resources to Kubernetes with Pulumi, if I make a mistake, Pulumi will wait for the Kubernetes resources to be healthy.

```
     Type                                                                               Name                               Status                  Info
 +   pulumi:pulumi:Stack                                                                aws-load-balancer-controller-dev   **creating failed**     1 error
 +   ├─ jaxxstorm:aws:loadbalancercontroller                                            foo                                created
 +   ├─ kubernetes:yaml:ConfigFile                                                      foo-crd                            created
 +   │  └─ kubernetes:apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1:CustomResourceDefinition             targetgroupbindings.elbv2.k8s.aws  created                 1 warning
 +   ├─ kubernetes:core/v1:Namespace                                                    foo-namespace                      created
 +   ├─ kubernetes:core/v1:Service                                                      foo-webhook-service                **creating failed**     1 error
 +   ├─ kubernetes:rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1:Role                                    foo-role                           created
 +   ├─ pulumi:providers:kubernetes                                                     k8s                                created
 +   ├─ aws:iam:Role                                                                    foo-role                           created
 +   │  └─ aws:iam:Policy                                                               foo-policy                         created
 +   ├─ kubernetes:core/v1:Secret                                                       foo-tls-secret                     created
 +   ├─ kubernetes:rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1:ClusterRole                             foo-clusterrole                    created
 +   ├─ kubernetes:admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1:ValidatingWebhookConfiguration  foo-validating-webhook             created                 1 warning
 +   ├─ kubernetes:admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1:MutatingWebhookConfiguration    foo-mutating-webhook               created                 1 warning
 +   └─ kubernetes:core/v1:ServiceAccount                                               foo-serviceAccount                 **creating failed**     1 error
 C
Diagnostics:
  kubernetes:core/v1:ServiceAccount (foo-serviceAccount):
    error: resource aws-load-balancer-controller/foo-serviceaccount was not successfully created by the Kubernetes API server : ServiceAccount "foo-serviceaccount" is invalid: metadata.labels: Invalid value: "arn:aws:iam::616138583583:role/foo-role-10b9499": a valid label must be an empty string or consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'MyValue',  or 'my_value',  or '12345', regex used for validation is '(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])?')

  kubernetes:core/v1:Service (foo-webhook-service):
    error: 2 errors occurred:
        * resource aws-load-balancer-controller/foo-webhook-service-4lpopjpr was successfully created, but the Kubernetes API server reported that it failed to fully initialize or become live: Resource operation was cancelled for "foo-webhook-service-4lpopjpr"
        * Service does not target any Pods. Selected Pods may not be ready, or field '.spec.selector' may not match labels on any Pods
```

Is there a way to disable this so that I don't have to send a signal to Pulumi to terminate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pulumi has special await logic on Kubernetes resources. You can read more about this [here](https://www.pulumi.com/blog/improving-kubernetes-management-with-pulumis-await-logic/)

Pulumi will wait for Kubernetes resources to be "healthy". The definition of "healthy" can change depending on the resource being created, but generally Pulumi will wait for the resource to:

- Exist
- Have a ready state (if the resources has one)

You can skip this logic by adding an annotation to that resource, like so:

```
pulumi.com/skipAwait: "true"
```

You can also change the timeout, or how long Pulumi will wait, using the following example:

```
pulumi.com/timeoutSeconds: 600
```

This gets added to any Kubernetes resource you're managing with Pulumi, so for example, a service resource might look like this (with Pulumi's typescript SDK):

```
const service = new k8s.core.v1.Service(`${name}-service`, {
  metadata: {
    namespace: "my-service",
  },
  annotations: {
    "pulumi.com/timeoutSeconds": "60" // Only wait 1 minute for pulumi to timeout
    "pulumi.com/skipAwait": "true" // don't use the await logic at all
}
  spec: {
    ports: [{
      port: 443,
      targetPort: 9443,
    }],
    selector: {
      "app.kubernetes.io/name": "my-deployment",
      "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "foo",
    },
 },
});
```

Comment: `annotations` should be inside `metadata`, if someone is wondering.